# React JS recursive tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree

I am trying to render a tree structure recursively using ReactJS. I did a vanilla example pretty quickly (below). Now I'm porting this to React and I've been looking at it for a while and can not figure out how to do it. I have included my React example under the vanilla one.

**Vanilla JS**

```
createTree(data, isSub, lev) {
let level = lev || 0;
let html = (isSub) ? '<div class="filter-body">' : ''; // Wrap with div if true
if (isSub) { level++; }

for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (typeof(data[i].nested_values) === 'object') {
        html += '<div class="filter-group level-' + level + '">';
        if (isSub) {
            html += '<div class="filter-heading">' + data[i].value + '</div>';
        } else { // Submenu found, but top level list item.
            html += '<div class="filter-heading">' + data[i].value + '</div>';
        }
        // Submenu found, call function recursively
        html += this.createTree(data[i].nested_values, true, level);
        html += '</div>';
    } else {
        html += '<span>' + data[i].value + '</span>' // No submenu, end of tree
    }

}
html += (isSub) ? '</div>' : '';
return html;
```

}

**ReactJS version**

I'm adding to an array then mapping over it to output in my render method. The part I'm struggling to wrap my head around is how to inject the recursive call.. I feel I'm very close but been looking at it for too long, any ideas?

```
createTree(data, isSub, lev) {
        let level = lev || 0;
        for (let i in data) {
            if (typeof(data[i].nested_values) === 'object') { // Sub array found, build structure
                this.tmpArrB.push(
                    <div class={"filter-group level-" + (level)}>
                        <div class="filter-heading">{data[i].value}</div>
                        {this.createTree(data[i].nested_values, true, level)} // How to do this properly?
                    </div>
                );
            } else { // No submenu, bottom of tree
                this.tmpArrB.push(
                    <span key={i}>
                        {data[i].value}               
                    </span>);
            }
        }
        this.tmpArr.push(<div className='filter-body open'>{this.tmpArrB}</div>);
    }
```

**Updated version (working)**

```
createSelectionHierarchy(data, isSub, level = 1) {
    let children = [];
    if (isSub) { level++; }
    for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (typeof(data[i].nested_values) === 'object') { // Sub array found, build structure
            children.push(
                <FilterItem key={i} data={data[i]} level={level}>
                    {this.createSelectionHierarchy(data[i].nested_values, true, level)}
                </FilterItem>
            );
        } else { // No submenu, bottom of tree
            children.push(
                <span key={i}>
                    {data[i].value}               
                </span>);
        }
    }
    return children;
}
```

**Dummy JSON**

```
{
    "possible_values": [{
        "value": "Fruit",
        "occurrence_count": 5,
        "nested_values": [{
            "value": "Berries",
            "occurrence_count": 3,
            "nested_values": [{
                "value": "Strawberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Blackberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Raspberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Redcurrant",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Blackcurrant",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Gooseberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Cranberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Whitecurrant",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Loganberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Strawberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }]
        }, {
            "value": "Tropical",
            "occurrence_count": 2,
            "nested_values": [{
                "value": "Pineapple",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Mango",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Guava",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Passion Fruit",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Dragon Fruit",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "value": "Vegetable",
        "occurrence_count": 2,
        "nested_values": [{
            "value": "Potato",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Leek",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Onion",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Sprout",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Carrot",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Runner Bean",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Swede",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Turnip",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Parsnip",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Kale",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Spinach",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Artichoke",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Broad Bean",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "French Bean",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Brocolli",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Cauliflower",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "White Cabbage",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Red Cabbage",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Savoy Cabbage",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Corn",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Courgette",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Mange Tout",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Sweet Potato",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }, {
            "value": "Pak Choi",
            "occurrence_count": 3
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: It depends on what output you want. The fact that you are adding the React elements to arrays makes things complicated. Ideally the function simply returns an element.

Comment: @FelixKling totally agree with u.. he can take advantage also of the concept of props as well as compo lifecycle

Comment: The reason for the array is because i wanted nested toggleable divs prob a better way- will get this working first then refactor

Comment: @FelixKling - how would I pass a custom object to the child components. The idea being, on each child I want the path within the json it came from e.g.

Level 1 - {value: "Fruit"}

Level 2 - {value: "Fruit", nested_values: [{ value: 'Tropical'}] }

Level 3 - {value: "Fruit", nested_values: [{ value: 'Tropical', nested_values:[{ value: 'Pineapple' }]}] }

I somehow need to get to the point where I select a tree element and the entire structure (json) of that is sent as an action to a Redux store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not different from any other recursive function. To make this work, the function has to return something though.

This line

```
{this.createTree(data[i].nested_values, true, level)} // How to do this properly?
```

means to pass the return value of `this.createTree` as child to an element. Since your function doesn't return anything, that doesn't work.

Corrected example:

```
createTree(data, isSub, lev) {
    let level = lev || 0;
    let children = [];
    for (let i in data) {
        if (typeof(data[i].nested_values) === 'object') { // Sub array found, build structure
            children.push(
                <div class={"filter-group level-" + (level)}>
                    <div class="filter-heading">{data[i].value}</div>
                    {this.createTree(data[i].nested_values, true, level)}
                </div>
            );
        } else { // No submenu, bottom of tree
            children.push(
                <span key={i}>
                    {data[i].value}               
                </span>
            );
        }
    }
    return <div className='filter-body open'>{children}</div>;
}
```

If `data` is an array, consider using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead.

Comment: I just missed the return!?

Comment: Well, the use of  `this.tmpArr` and `this.tmpArrB` was also questionable.

Comment: Ah yes i see what you have done! Thanks Felix will try this out when i get home

Comment: Worked well thanks Felix - I refactored it heavily and now think it looks much better, updated my answer. Any input would be most appreciated!